# Why can't I cast from 1 type to another when both share interface

Tags: c#, polymorphism

This is a demo console app (Which you should be able to just copy and paste into VS if you wanted)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Temporary t = new Temporary(); //I know it should be ICompany t
        t.Name = "My Name";

        var com = (ICompany)t;
        var result = (Company)com; //Kaboom

    }
}
public class Temporary : ICompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company : ICompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICompany
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Hopefully the code above is straight forward.

My question is about the cast and why it fails. I know I can change the original variable `t` to type ICompany (As per the comments), but my quesiton is about why the cast fails as it currently is.

My understanding (which hopefully explains where I'm going wrong) is

```
var com = (ICompany)t
```

Cast `t`, which is of Type `Temporary` into `ICompany`. This works great as `Temporary implements`ICompany`

This means, `t` is now of type `ICompany`. So, hopefully

```
var result = (Company)com; //Kaboom
```

this converts `com` (type ICompany) into `Company`

Why does this fail and why does it know that `t` is still of type `Temporary`

Comment: The code still knows what the real type is (it has to!), and `com` is not a `Company`. Simple as that.

Comment: Because the Actual type of t is Temporary, and Temporary cannot be casted to Company.

Comment: So other than providing a mechanism to map them, is there another option?

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in this question. No, `t` is not of type `ICompany`, it is of type `Temporary`. You've cast that to `ICompany` and stored that into `com`, but `t` is still of type `Temporary`. And this is not at all possible through interfaces, to silently convert one type to another, you're just treating the object as being of a specific interface type, it is not a `Company`, it is still a `Temporary`.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions No - a cast means "treat this object as another type".  Since a `Temporary` _is not_ a `Company`, you can't treat it like it is one.  You need to map it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some confusion in this question, which is probably what prompted it.

This statement:

> This means, t is now of type ICompany. So, hopefully

is incorrect. No, `t` is still of type `Temporary`, as per its declaration:

```
Temporary t = new Temporary();
```

There are actually two places in this line where type is important. It is the actual type of the object you constructed, and the type of the variable you placed the reference into.

Sure, you could write it like this:

```
ICompany t = new Temporary();
```

But that would only change the type of the variable, the underlying object is still of type `Temporary`.

You're then trying to cast the actual object, which is still a `Temporary`, into a `Company`, but this will fail, since a `Temporary` is not a `Company`.

They both, however, implement the same `ICompany` interface, which is great, you can talk to both types of objects with only the knowledge that they implement something in common, but it is not the same type of object and you cannot convert from one to another.

Answer (score 2):

Just because `com` is an `ICompany` it doesn't mean it points to a `Company` instance. It could point to a (potentially) infinite number of types that derive from `ICompany`. Yes, you can look at the code and know this, but that's not how the compiler see it.

This is especially true in your case as the actual type is `Temporary`, not `Company`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just cast the Company class into the Temporary class, because although they both derivate from ICompany and have the same fields, the compiler still thinks that they're different classes. The only allowed kind of class casting is from a child class to its parent class. In that case, you will in fact put a "mask" on the child class which hides its exclusive fields, and that will have it behave as its parent, but you still will be able to convert it back to the original child class.

Comment: They don't both derive from `ICompany`. Rather, they both implement the `ICompany` interface. The difference is very important.

Comment: That was what I meant. The classes both implement the same interface, so they're both "child classes" of that interface (I know that it's not the same as a parent class, because interfaces are completely abstract, but hey, for the means of explaining why he can't cast that there's no big difference).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an interface to a implementation like that. Casting is NOT a conversion. Casting only means: "take this item and treat it as if it was some other type", but the data underneath remains the same. This way you can cast any speciffic type to more general one - the other way is allowed only if object beneath is of type you are casting to (or to some other, iherited type). Imagine that your classes definitions would look like this:

```
public class Temporary : ICompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company : ICompany
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

If you'd call `((Company)t).OtherProperty`, you'd try to use a property, that `Temporary` t object doesn't possess. Compiler does not let you to do so.